# Dynamic Selection of TransactionManager Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am converting my existing Spring Application to a Spring Boot Application. In my existing application, we have the need to connect to multiple databases and we had achieved this by having multiple data sources defined and fetching the corresponding bean based on the condition. The transaction manager were also selected using a custom implementation of TransactionInterceptor.

```
@Override
public TransactionAttributeSource getTransactionAttributeSource() {
    final TransactionAttributeSource origTxAttrSource = super.getTransactionAttributeSource();
    return new TransactionAttributeSource() {

        @Override
        public TransactionAttribute getTransactionAttribute(final Method method, final Class<?> targetClass) {
            TransactionAttribute txAttr = origTxAttrSource.getTransactionAttribute(method, targetClass);
            String database = (String) ThreadContext.get("database");
            if (database != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(database)) {
                if (txAttr instanceof DefaultTransactionAttribute) {
                    ((DefaultTransactionAttribute) txAttr).setQualifier("txManager" + database);
                }
            }
            return txAttr;
        }
    };
}
```

Through a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` we were including this interceptor

```
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
         String[] names = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(TransactionInterceptor.class);
        for (String name : names) {
            BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name);
            bd.setBeanClassName(MyTransactionInterceptor.class.getName());

        }
}
```

This worked perfectly fine in Spring 4.X.

Now that we are moving towards Spring Boot, I am trying to convert the same approach. I can see that the bean factory is getting called but I don't find calls happening to the Custom Interceptor class. This results in my `@Transactional` to fail as there are more than one qualifying bean.

Am I missing something with regards to the Spring Boot Configuration?

(This approach of dynamic transaction management was through a reference blog http://blog.tirasa.net/dynamic-springs--at-transactional.html)

Comment: Add the exception and you might want do exclude the `EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration` from kicking in as that enables transaction management. Although it should already backoff if you yourself add `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement annotation is not present. Basically, I have two transaction managers define (one for PostGre and another for MySQL). The exception I get is when the Transaction Proxy is being executed that there were two qualifying beans. Will post the stacktrace shortly.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: postgreTxManager,mysqlTxManager
at  (so on until ) org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

Comment: Can you show me the code, which "worked perfectly fine in Spring 4.X"?
With your code in question I got same behaviour - custom Interceptor didn't run. But adding 2 null methods as in your answer also didn't help - I got NULL here: `final TransactionAttributeSource origTxAttrSource = super.getTransactionAttributeSource();`      and NullPointerException later in `origTxAttrSource.getTransactionAttribute(method, targetClass)`


I use hibernate and spring 5.x

Comment: @AHTOH - The code that is present as part of the question is from the Spring 4.X project. Per Spring documentation, getTransactionAttributeSource will return null only if the method is non-transactional. Is that true in your case?

Comment: If I add 2 NULL methods, than first call to `public TransactionAttributeSource getTransactionAttributeSource()` happens during initialization. And second - when `@Transaction` method is called

Comment: Stacktrace `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at my.DynamicTransactionInterceptor$1.getTransactionAttribute(DynamicTransactionInterceptor.java:31)
 at TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
 at TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
 at ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 at JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
 at $Proxy56.getOssAccount(Unknown Source)
 at my.RequestServiceImpl.getOssAccount(RequestServiceImpl.java:38)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer turned out to be setting the factory classes and the factory bean name to null which resulted in the transaction interceptor being invoked. I am yet to figure out how this affects the interceptor call as with the values in these fields (they point to the ProxyTransaction classes as transactionInterceptor bean is created by it).

The final code was of the form -

TransactionInterceptor Class

```
@Component
public class TransactionInterceptorReplacer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

@Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
        String[] names = factory.getBeanNamesForType(TransactionInterceptor.class);
        for (String name : names) {
            BeanDefinition bd = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
            bd.setBeanClassName(MyTransactionInterceptor.class.getName());
            bd.setFactoryBeanName(null);
            bd.setFactoryMethodName(null);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code is not (more) working due to NPE in `TransactionAttribute txAttr = origTxAttrSource.getTransactionAttribute(method, targetClass);` (`origTxAttrSource` is `null`) as described by @ahtoh above.

Comment: I proposed another solution to the problem in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24291